# How to make TV item expandable when be selected, like homepage's recommendation?

Tags: android, android-tv

In AndroidTV's homepage, when user selects a recommendation video, the item will expand itself and shows more information than the other unselect items.

Screenshot is here:

[image]

In my TV application, I extends the `VerticalGridFragment` as the `GridFragment` to show TV shows. And also extends the `Presenter` to set the item layout. However, when item is selected, the item only scale bigger, but not show more information just like homepage's recommendation.

How can I get this effect in my TV application's Presenter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I found the solution: In `Presenter` , we will create a `ViewHolder` to show, maybe like this:

```
public class GridItemPresenter extends Presenter {
......

public GridItemPresenter(Fragment fragment) {
    this.mainFragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    // Here is the view we want to show.
    final RichCardView cardView = new RichCardView(parent.getContext());

    // We should change something when the view is focused: show more information.
    cardView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, final boolean isFocused) {
            updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, isFocused);
            cardView.setSelected(isFocused);
        }
    });
    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    ......
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}

private static void updateCardBackgroundColor(RichCardView view, boolean selected) {
    ......
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    RichCardView cardView = (RichCardView) viewHolder.view;
    ......
}

@Override
public void onUnbindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    RichCardView cardView = (RichCardView) viewHolder.view;
    ......
}
}
```

`ViewHolder` is a container which holds the showing view, in upon code , view is `RichCardView`. Here are some of the `RichCardView` codes:

```
public class RichCardView extends RelativeLayout {

public RichCardView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public RichCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v17.leanback.R.attr.imageCardViewStyle);
}

public RichCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lb_rich_card_view, this);

   ......
}

@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    super.setSelected(selected);
    if (selected) {
        // when be selected, set some views Visible to show more information.
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEpisodeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // when not be selected, hide those views.
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEpisodeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

When the view is selected , we show more views to show more information. Otherwise, we hide some views to hide some information.

And yes, `RichCardView` is simply extends `RelativeLayout`. You can also extend any `ViewGroup` you want. If you want to change lively, just add some animations when change view's visibility.

Comment: how to start design this kind of layout? can you please share some demo code to make this layout design?

Answer (score 3):

You may refer the implementation of ImageCardView. It has a method *setInfoVisibility* and *setExtraVisibility* which controls the behavior of expandable CardView. When CARD_REGION_VISIBLE_ACTIVATED is set to argument, it will behaves that the region will not appear when user is selecting header, and the region will appear when user move to RowsFragment.

**Update (2015.10.26)**

When you want to expand the card only when selected CARD_REGION_VISIBLE_SELECTED can be used.

Below is sample code (updated), which should be implemented in the Presenter class.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(mContext);
    cardView.setCardType(BaseCardView.CARD_TYPE_INFO_UNDER);
    cardView.setInfoVisibility(BaseCardView.CARD_REGION_VISIBLE_SELECTED);
    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.fastlane_background));
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}
```

Details are explained at the bottom of [this tutorial](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-3-105.html).

Comment: What is "Extra" ? I can't find anything that is hidden or displayed if you change `setExtraVisibility`
Actually I'm not sure you answerd the question @im-superman asked. He wanted to display some additional inforamtion when one ImageCardView is selected, not when RowsFragment is focused.

Comment: @oleynikd thanks for comment, I updated answer.
For the "Extra", I think it is NOT used in ImageCardView. I could find ImageCardView layout at sdk/extras/android/support/v17/leanback/res/layout/lb_image_card_view.xml, and there are attributes `lb:layout_viewType` "main" and "info" but not "extra". Maybe "extra" is for your customized CardView which extends BaseCardView.

Comment: It will work on mobile app as well, you can try installing Android TV app onto your Android mobile to see if how it works. 
But the UI design is fully optimized for TV usage, so I won't recommend to use it for mobile.
Also, Leanback library works from SDK level 21 (which Android TV appears), so if you publish app for mobile using leanback library then its support version may be limited.